# Looker Studio: Calculated field multiplying rather than dividing

Tags: looker-studio, looker

I'm completely new to Looker Studio so apologies if this is a simple question. I've spent some looking for an answer but not found anything yet.

What I am trying to do is divide revenue by the number of queries received. For example:

Revenue = £5000
Total Queries = 5 Revenue per query = £1000`

The 'Total Queries' field I have is already a calculated field, counting up two different types of queries.

My formula so far is:
Revenue / Total Queries

But unfortunately this is multiplying rather than dividing. If it was the example above I would get a figure of £50,000.

I have tried adding SUM() in a variety of places, but I just can't get the correct figure.

Can anyone kindly assist?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following approch

```
Revenue / (Total Queries * 1.0)
```

this is probably happening because looker studio treats integer division differently from floating-point division here by multiplying by 1.0 converts the integer division to floating-point division.

additionally if the above approch did not work .

```
dimension: revenue {
  type: number
  sql: ${TABLE}.revenue ;;
}

dimension: total_queries {
  type: number
  sql: ${TABLE}.total_queries ;;
}

measure: revenue_per_query {
  type: number
  sql: ${revenue} / ${total_queries} ;;
}
```

it will ensure that all are the number type ,also it is a better way to handle.